# Has BLM raised over 1 billion dollars but not yet performed any neighborhood cleanup, school funding, food aid or housing services?

Tags: united-states, politics, social-media, black-lives-matter

[image: Fact Check]

[This Twitter post by James Woods](https://twitter.com/RealJamesWoods/status/1299748807844921344) claims that the Black Lives Matter movement has raised over 1 billion dollars but has not yet performed any neighborhood cleanup, college funding, student economic support, food aid, or housing services. Are these claims accurate?

Comment: I don't think it follows that the picture is intended as a claim about what the money is being spent on. The charitable explanation is that it's intended as an illustration of the unjustified-in-Woods'-view political reach of the movement.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: If it's not actively insinuated, it's tacitly accepted that people might get the wrong impression.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "They haven't done these worthy activities... instead I want you to think they bought a couple of buses" would be a charitable reading of that post.  Both the explicit and implicate statements are wrong, but that doesn't really matter since the intention of the post (and repost) is to turn people away from BLM.

Comment: @MBraedley I see. It *was* a political jab. [Sorry, we don't care about your political opinion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3858/11643). I'm leaving your original comment because it makes a good point about interpreting the claim.

Comment: One of the issues here is that the literal text of the claim is framed as implying something much larger. I've posted a question on Meta asking whether we should challenge the frame of a statement as well as the text. https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/how-should-frame-challenges-to-claims-be-handled

Comment: @fredsbend I never intended to espouse my own ideology, just frame the ideology of James Woods based on what he tweeted.  I do see though that aspects of my political ideology can be gleaned from how I wrote that comment, and apologize for that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The other answers have explained that doing the things mentionned in the tweet is not the goal of BLM, that is not easy to estimate accurately how much money they have raised, or that the buses in the picture were not paid with donated money.

But it might be worth adding that the claim that BLM "has not yet performed any neighborhood cleanup, college funding, student economic support, food aid, or housing services" is not even true.

For example :

- the Chicago BLM chapter has installed a [foodbox](https://www.blacklivesmatterchicago.com/foodbox/) in order to provide food for those who need it.
- the Philadelphia chapter apparently has a [campaign](http://www.blmphilly.com/donate/fundraising-campaigns/mutual-aid/) to help people obtain school supplies and food (among other things).
- BLM members have organised a clean-up event in [Aiken](https://www.aikenstandard.com/news/black-lives-matter-hosts-litter-cleanup-along-laurens-street/article_d3fcef9a-be0e-11ea-b2c3-2f0ba740166a.html).
- the (unofficial?) [Louisville](https://louisvillefuture.com/archived-news/black-lives-matters-starts-housing-programs-to-ensure-low-income-families-can-stay-in-the-west-end/) chapter has bought and renovated houses to house poor families.

Comment: This answer is better and clearer than the others in showing that the statement is just flat wrong

Comment: @Mari-LouA For the foodbox, the BLM Chicago website mentions that they accept financial donations for this project; I'm not sure if this is supposed to show up in the 1 billion dollars of the tweet though. I've changed the link to that, since the BLM website links to the same news article.

Comment: One to add to the list perhaps -- BLM Toronto raised more than $130,000 for black families financially struggling during Covid-19 (https://www.gofundme.com/f/black-emergency-support-fund)

Comment: @CGCampbell "the real issue should be that the so-called BLM collections of funding should be forced to be unambiguously singular" So much for freedom of association, then.

Comment: "The other answers have explained that doing the things mentionned in the tweet is not the goal of BLM"... I think that's the absolutely crucial thing in handling the original question. Any considerations of the worthiness of the cause or the wisdom of donating to it become irrelevant.

Answer (score 177):

So first of all, there is no central BLM organisation collecting donations. There are local organisations, some named BLM (or some variation thereof) and some which existed prior to BLM and support their cause and collect money using the name or slogan BLM. There is one [central organisation](https://blacklivesmatter.com/chapters/) which organises 16 local chapters in North America. However, there are plenty of BLM chapters unaffiliated with this organisation. For a US example, the [BLM Austin](https://www.facebook.com/BlackLivesMatterAustin/) organisation is unaffiliated with the umbrella organisation. There are also BLM organisations in countries such as the [UK](https://blacklivesmatter.uk/), [Australia](https://www.facebook.com/BlackLivesMatterAus/), and [Germany](https://www.blacklivesmatterberlin.de/) which are independent.

The specific purposes of different BLM organisations differ, but they are typically not a charity aimed at providing scholarships, providing food, or providing housing. The movement is about protesting police brutality and overpolicing aimed at Black communities, but specific chapters may have different ways of going about this. [Money collected as part of the BLM movement has gone to things like bail funds, political campaigns, the ACLU.](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/14/us/politics/black-lives-matter-racism-donations.html) and Black-led charities such as Color of Change. Each of those organisations have done different things with their money. For this reason, it's impossible to say how much money they have raised in total.

That specific photo and those buses are not affiliated with any BLM organisation. They belong to the Toronto Raptors NBA team who repainted their buses in support of BLM in July. [Here is the source of the image](https://twitter.com/Raptors/status/1281302322287706114), which has circulated widely with various different captions falsely implying that they were purchased with BLM funds.

Comment: "it's impossible to say how much money they have raised in total." I don't think I understand, I was under the impression that public charities have to disclose how much money they get from donations?

Comment: @Jordy Yes, but first you need to find all charities that take donations in the BLM name, which is highly non-trivial since we're not talking about a single organisation. Add that there are BLM organisations in numerous countries, all of which likely have different rules and procedures for disclosing donations and it will be quite the task to figure out a number.

Comment: BTW, https://www.charitynavigator.org/ein/474143254. It states that BLM had at least 1 program dedicated to providing for the poor.

Comment: This answer has most of the direct answer in that nyt link, which you don't really discuss. It's great that you're addressing other things like the buses, but as for the direct answer (where does the donation money go) there's really only that link.

Comment: @Oddthinking `seems to be widely accepted as a central BLM organisation accepting donations` - have you got a reference for that?

Comment: I understand I'm being pedantic, but the question asked isn't "where does the money go". Woods' claims the money _hasn't_ gone to 5 things, the question is only asking if it really hasn't gone there. If the question is really "where does the money go?", then ask that.

Comment: @CGCampbell: I think does answering where does the money goes matter, as well as identifying the buses. In the larger context, claims such as this tweet are about more important for their implications; and this tweet seems to imply that the money raised was spent poorly (notably on sleek buses) rather than to help. Showing that the money was spent to help (and not on those buses) debunks the _implications_ of the tweet, and is necessary for completeness.

Comment: @LioElbammalf: Circumstantial evidence: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lives_Matter) mentions the organisation (and no other organisations) in the introductory section and in the summary panel. Of the 6 BLM-related Twitter accounts mentioned [in this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-race-ethnicity-and-politics/article/what-kind-of-movement-is-black-lives-matter-the-view-from-twitter/375801268123BCA397284EFBE36C9F4E/core-reader#), it dominates the follower count (almost 1 million, compared to less than 100K for each of the others)

Comment: Even if you don't think that "one central organisation which organises 16 local chapters in North America" qualifies as a "central BLM organisation collecting donations" (I don't understand the logic here - they clearly collect donations, with a big Donate button on their page header; and the mere existence of other chapters doesn't even dissuade *you* from using the word "central"), it seems like a perfectly reasonable and expected referent for the term "BLM" as used in the original tweet.

Comment: On the other hand, just because not all local chapters are organized by blacklivesmatter.com exist, doesn't mean they aren't collecting donations. I see no reason why it would be inappropriate, inaccurate, misleading etc. to tally those donations and attribute them as funds that "BLM" has raised.

Comment: As for the purpose of the organizations and what the money is spent on vs. what James Woods (a) implies it's spent on or (b) thinks it should be spent on instead: whether it's spent on the specific things described in the tweet is the only question of fact here. The rest is about politics, not skepticism.

Comment: The movement is about more then just *protesting police brutality and overpolicing aimed at Black communities* if you go to the website of the central organization you find *issues concerning racial injustice, police brutality, criminal justice reform, Black immigration, economic injustice, LGBTQIA+ and human rights, environmental injustice, access to healthcare, access to quality education, and voting rights and suppression*.

Comment: This answer gives some context on the structure (or lack thereof) of the BLM movement but stops short of debunking the claim clearly. And a lot of the comments are clearly debating a red herring. @Arnaud D.'s answer gives several examples of BLM-affiliated groups providing food and school supplies

Comment: This claim is false. In order for a claim to be true, all portions of the claim must be true. If you interpret it as BLM is this giant umbrella of all black-focused initiatives, then all of the works those groups have done will apply, thus making the second part of the claim totally untrue. If you construe BLM as being just the primary BLM group, then it is again untrue because they are not near the $1b mark. No interpretation yields a true statement for BOTH claims in the original statement.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The problem with that (and I _do_ agree with you to an extent, I just am a stickler for the answer having to deal with what is asked, not what is _imagined_ to have been asked) is that we can't know ALL of the places the money has gone. We should be able to find out that is has/hasn't gone to those 5 things. See Amaud D.'s answer.

Comment: @Nucleon That is an answer, not comment.

Comment: @Nucleon Exactly. Besides, it's not clear that the particular organisation discussed in the comments (the one running blacklivesmatter.com) has _not_ used donations for any of the causes in question. The fact that they don't explain on their website is not a good look but it doesn't prove the negative at all

Answer (score 98):

## What is "BLM"?

> It's been 7 years since BLM was formed.

This statement is [generally true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lives_Matter).

> They have raised over a billion dollars.

This statement is ill-formed.  As many have noted, "BLM" is not the name of an unambiguous revenue-raising organization.  Rather, it is the name of a social movement plus numerous legal organizations, some of which are registered charities.  So the antecedent for "they" is not something for which "raising a billion dollars" is a well-defined statement.

For instance, it appears that the movement did not receive significant donations [until 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lives_Matter#Funding_of_the_movement), at least, which contradicts the implication that BLM had "7 years of funding" with which to perform social services.  Illustrating the complexity of what it means to "donate to BLM", consider this description of an [early donation](https://www.politico.com/story/2015/11/major-donors-consider-funding-black-lives-matter-215814) from Democracy Alliance:

> It’s donated more than $200,000 to the Black Lives Matter movement since Brown’s killing. According to its entry on a philanthropy website, more than $61,000 went directly to organizers and organizations on the ground in Ferguson and Baltimore, where the death of Freddie Gray in police custody in April sparked a more recent wave of Black Lives-related protests. An additional $115,000 went to groups that have sprung up to support the movement.

The Ford Foundation reportedly donated [$100 million](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/aug/16/black-lives-matter-cashes-100-million-liberal-foun/) to...BLM?  Well, it's not quite that simple.  The donation went to [M4BL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movement_for_Black_Lives), which includes the Black Lives Matter Network as a *member*, among many other groups.  So, either this money went to "BLM" + others, and thus you can't really count it as $100 million for "BLM", or we can count M4BL as falling under the "BLM" umbrella.  But if we do that, where do we draw the line?  Does every black advocacy group therefore qualify as part of the BLM movement?

Maybe it seems easy to include M4BL under the BLM umbrella.  No problem.  But where does Woods get the "$1 billion" figure from?  We don't know, because he doesn't cite a source.  We do know that a lot of money has flowed towards black causes recently, so let's take a look at another source.  NBC collected this [summary list](https://www.nbcnews.com/business/consumer/want-know-where-all-those-corporate-donations-blm-are-going-n1225371), from which I will include just a few excerpts for illustrative purposes:

> Airbnb
>
> The home-sharing site tweeted on June 1 that it will be giving a total of $500,000 to the NAACP and Black Lives Matter.
>
> Amazon
>
> The retail and technology giant announced on June 3 that it plans to donate a total of $10 million to 11 organizations, including the ACLU, Equal Justice Initiative, and the NAACP.
>
> ...
>
> Glossier
>
> The beauty brand released a statement on Instagram saying the company planned to donate $500,000 to “organizations focused on combating racial injustice.”
>
> The statement specifically cited Black Lives Matter, The NAACP Legal Defense and Educational Fund, The Equal Justice Initiative, The Marsha P. Johnson Institute, and We The Protesters.

As you can see, the NAACP figures prominently, and corporations are giving to numerous and diverse organizations.  Does the NAACP count as "BLM"?  If so, Woods can back up his start date by more than a century.  If not, it's hard to say that all this money is going to "BLM" (whether that means the movement, any one of numerous organizations featuring the name, or the constellation of social justice organizations loosely affiliated with the movement).

## What are BLM's goals?

In the previous section, we did not establish *who* or *what* constitutes "BLM as a donation recipient", instead offering a large variety of possible answers.  This points to the extreme difficulty in discovering the *goals* of donation recipients, something directly implied and defined by Woods' tweet.

Perhaps the closest BLM proxy we can hope for is the [Black Lives Matter Global Network Foundation](https://www.influencewatch.org/non-profit/black-lives-matter-foundation/).  So let's see how its goals align with the goals of the putative BLM imagined by Woods.  Let's start with the mission statement on the [BLM website](https://blacklivesmatter.com/what-we-believe/).

> Four years ago, what is now known as the Black Lives Matter Global Network began to organize. It started out as a chapter-based, member-led organization whose mission was to build local power and to intervene when violence was inflicted on Black communities by the state and vigilantes.

Now, I don't see any direct or implied mission to clean up neighborhoods, buy school supplies, send children to college, feed hungry people, or provide housing.  The statement is clearly about *violence against the black community*.  Therefore, Mr. Woods' tweet is clearly a straw man argument in which he sets up his own personal vision of what BLM means, and then knocks it down with an unrelated picture for good measure.

So, while the claim may be *literally true*, it is analogous to saying:

> James Woods has received millions of dollars in income over the last several decades, but hasn't saved a single baby from a burning building.

The implication, of course, is that James Woods is a terrible human being that doesn't care about babies, or burning babies, but that he has the means to do so, increasing the monstrosity of his indifference.  The statement above, so far as I know, is *literally true*, but *rhetorically invalid*, to the extent that James Woods' acting in no way implies some obligation to go save babies from burning buildings.

Thus, the question:

> Are these claims accurate?

is, IMO, the *wrong question*.  A better question would be:

> Is the implication that BLM has grossly misspent its donations accurate?

That's a much bigger question that requires a much longer answer which is out of scope here.

Comment: So, in short, the answer to this question is "Yes, this is true," then?

Comment: @nick012000: The answer is that the q should should have been closed as rubbish. Somehow the mods did manage to close a rubbish question about something that Trump said, recently. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48364/are-there-80-million-unsolicited-ballots-being-sent-in-the-usa

Comment: @nick012000 Saying something is "true" often has the connotation that it is not just "factually correct", but also _honest_ and _meaningful_. This answer rather clearly demonstrates that this statement is neither, so headlining it with "true" but would be misleading.

Comment: @nick012000 In addition to the dishonesty of the implication, the statement itself is a lot vaguer than it tries to suggest it is, given the fuzziness of what does and what does not qualify as "black lives matter".  It's possible that if you sat him down he might be able to come up with a carefully selected slice that had received that much money but not done any of those specific things, but it's honestly more likely that he's just throwing out bald assertions in a way that can't be easily disproven.

Comment: @nick012000 in short, the answer is neither "Yes" or "No", it's "[Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29#In_popular_culture)". Or in plain English "The question is flawed in a way that there is no useful knowledge to gain from answering it".

Comment: @nick012000 The answer is "The statement is vague enough that it can be both true and untrue depending on how you define 'BLM'."

Comment: "*Does the NAACP count as "BLM"? If so, Woods can back up his start date by more than a century.*" But if he did, his claim of lack of social involvement clearly becomes false.

Comment: @Fizz Closing and reopening is not the purview solely of the moderators. If you find "question is rubbish" a legitimate reason to vtc, then do so. Whereas your Trump question example is both unclear in the claim and a current event (both explicit close reasons).

Answer (score 18):

[Johanna's answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/48411/38337) has already told a lot about the fact that "BLM" can refer to many things (including organizations that do contribute to the causes mentioned in the question, and also ones that do not).

I do want to address one major fallacy in the tweet, which has been the subject of a lot of comments on the question and on Johanna's answer and in the world in general. Johanna brushed on this briefly in her last paragraph, but I would like to go into more detail. The picture in the tweet shows a picture of buses for the Toronto Raptors NBA (basketball) team, which is extremely misleading because it has nothing to do with the "billion dollars" mentioned in the tweet. The Toronto Raptors are worth about [$2.1 billion](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/02/11/the-latest-forbes-nba-valuations-show-how-much-winning-can-pay-off.html) and none of it came from BLM donations or anything of that sort; it came from selling seats at basketball games, selling merchandise, and similar channels. Furthermore, NBA players ***do*** spend a lot of their money on direct philanthropy, especially those mentioned in the tweet (school, food, housing, Black neighborhoods). One of the many examples, is the [school built by LeBron James](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Promise_School).

The picture tries to misrepresent buses owned by the Toronto Raptors basketball team, as being bought by leaders of the BLM movement from the "billion dollars" they have received in donations and that is just absolutely false; but for anyone that didn't just happen to be such a big fan of the Raptors that they've seen those buses when watching Raptors games, they may actually think those buses have something to do with BLM as the tweet suggests (this has already happened to a few people that wrote comments here).

**Finally**, the tweet, which is from 29 August 2020, is actually just a re-tweet of something that has been around since [more than a month earlier](https://www.facebook.com/brushfiretactical/photos/a.1546783892262186/2686543574952873/?type=3&__xts__%5B0%5D=68.ARAKz_q_a_qFDBMdqlPJYGjIMRuCfxcys4Yjxi_5tRuREZaBPBijFcEdsYDk5Ec_3YGsY-Z9FrT-no6RLJJ6pHLRZe9f-8A-vlDhlueHJma4ER_fOJUTbk2dsPUm7Cf8uwRMXwM-HNmE-gYV-WhOiVv1sYbGtXE8bSRlFynMcxK7uwfQlyRSkJwn-uxQiw1SZaNR4o4371_GEYAdlazchUE4q98aL4kBH5GDgiBWGIDSUtyuoTPn_HKCUMuZrqLuRDFNrBmJDGox_a3Xo8BQLzMhaPim3pBTez6pDRUTtCB6GNQu9LIdKAelt3zRP-5rfamCHSkW) (at least) and Facebook already marked it as "misinformation" which you will see if you click on the link earlier in this sentence. So the tweet shown in the question, is not actually the original source.

Answer (score 13):

## No

### BLM is not one organization

This has been covered by other answers, but just so this answer is complete on its own: There is not one single organization that is BLM. Instead, BLM is a social movement, ander there are lots of groups in it, some of them having "BLM" in their name. Additionally, though I haven't heard of an instance of this yet, it is entirely possible for a group or organization carrying "BLM" or variations thereof in their name without being part of the social movement at all. This happened with other social movement names, e.g. a lawyer in Germany not associated with the movement founded Fridays for Future e.V. and tried to sue fridays for future for their domain name fridaysforfuture.de (German [article](https://www.domainalliance.de/top-level-domain/streit-um-eine-domain/) only, sorry). Something similar happened with a group of actors [pretending](https://mobile.twitter.com/WolfTheRed/status/1270369754432356352) to be a group associated with the Black Panthers.

**tl;dr**: all claims of the form "BLM did x", under the premise that BLM is one organization or actor instead of a diverse movement, can only be factually false.

### BLM groups have done those things

Quoting from the comments:

> With respect to "fed the hungry" and "donated to a food bank", it seems that at least the Chicago BLM chapter has organized some things in that area blacklivesmatterchicago.com/foodbox; Philadelphia also has some similar activity blmphilly.com/donate/fundraising-campaigns/mutual-aid

> BTW, charitynavigator.org/ein/474143254. It states that BLM had at least 1 program dedicated to providing for the poor.

Additionally, there were many reports of spontaneous mutual aid and direct action in the context of BLM protests, e.g. during the Capitol Hill Organized Protest ([CHOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitol_Hill_Autonomous_Zone#Culture_and_amenities))

### The tweet is fallacious

Regarding the willfully misleading picture I quote from an other answer:

> The picture tries to misrepresent buses owned by the Toronto Raptors basketball team, as being bought by leaders of the BLM movement from the "billion dollars" they have received in donations, and that is just absolutely false

I also want to add that the used hashtags ("burn", loot" and "murder") clearly aim to discredit BLM, without providing any factual information.

There is also no source for the amount of donations, and while others have already explained the difficulties in estimating how much money the BLM movement in its entirety has *actually* collected since its beginning, I want to emphasize that this number seems completely made up, and not the result of methodological errors.

### Summary

1. No organization named "BLM" has generated over a billion dollars in donations. How much money was donated to the social movement is unclear.
2. Groups and people in the context of BLM protests have engaged in mutual aid, including most examples giving in the tweet.
3. The tweet is being willfully misleading.